# Types with identical fully qualified names in LinqPad

Tags: c#, linqpad

Is there any way to use types with identical names and namespaces in LinqPad queries?

PS: Yes, this is that rare use case for 'extern alias' C# construct.

PPS: particular example of well known clashing types: s3.codeplex.com vs. AWSSDK.

Comment: Can you load them through their assemblies?

Comment: What complicates my case is that I'm forced to use both assemblies simultaneously, I'll update the question.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but if you can get the `Type` object for each through their respective assemblies, that should work. In any case you need to post some code.